# How to get object property?

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code, like this:

```
let a = { b: 3, c: this.b }
```

The code doesn't work and returns "undefined". How do I access property b on property c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to `get`?

=> use `get`

```js
let a = { 
  b: 3, 
  get c() { 
    return this.b; 
  } 
}
console.log(a.b, a.c);
```